# Answer on What is it about the blues chord progression that makes the blues feel?

Tags: discussion

Here we have a very knowledgable user who has chosen to mutilate what could have been a good post with nonsense:

***[What is it about the blues chord progression that makes the blues feel?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/69960/what-is-it-about-the-blues-chord-progression-that-makes-the-blues-feel/69985#69985)***

*If you've ever tried to swim one of the wider reaches of the Missisippi with a pack of hell hounds/betrayed women/husbands/prison guards snapping at your rear end, you just may approach an appreciation of just how broad and muddy any definition of the blues has to be.*

I'd allow some poetic license for that, but it continues on, and then we get to this:

***And then there are the lyrics. A sure-fire way to kill the blues feelin' is to talk about First World problems: 'I Cain't get no Signal';'I Need Me some Single Origin Beans' or 'She Un-Friended Me When I Wore The Same Dress'. Not cool. However, a Jewish man writing about the sick allure of a fascist rally is right up there for blues-approved subversion with Red House or Empty Bed Blues, so, as long as you get the irony, the song is about industrial-scale sufferin'.***

---

> Is this song about a "first world", "second world", or "third world"
>   problem?
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1j_9BDM14Q

---

***It sounds as blues as the smack of a broken wine bottle across your jaw/head, at midnight, by the railroad tracks, behind the cotton gin***  - Is music arising from such experiences more "bluesy" than this, recorded by a white guy in 1967 - somebody raised by a middle class family in Chicago:

> The Paul Butterfield Blues Band - Driftin' and Driftin
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLFlMbyA0r8

---

The whole post is filled with ridiculous social/political innuendo. It implies some sort of "ownership" over blues music- bad news IMO. About the same as saying only Austrians can play Mozart

***NOBODY OWNS THE BLUES, OR ANY OTHER MUSIC.***

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76246/discussion-on-question-by-stinkfoot-answer-on-what-is-it-about-the-blues-chord-p).

Answer (score 3):

It is a poor answer, sure, as it waffles and doesn't actually answer the question, but I disagree with your claim that it is "offensive, racist, antisemitic political material."

See the authors comment on his post.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76200/discussion-on-answer-by-doktor-mayhem-answer-on-what-is-it-about-the-blues-chord).

Answer (score 3):

I'll just outline the way I read the post....

- Firstly, there's a genuine appreciation of *Chain Lightning* as an example of blues, despite some elements of the song (in particular the chord progression) not adhering to blues 'norms'. This is used to illustrate the idea that blues is a flexible genre.
- Then, the idea that there are *some* limits on what could be considered the blues - for example, moaning about silly things:

> A sure-fire way to kill the blues feelin' is to talk about First World problems: 'I Cain't get no Signal';'I Need Me some Single Origin Beans' or 'She Un-Friended Me When I Wore The Same Dress'. Not cool.

I do see that the phrase "First-world problems" is a little unfortunate - to those unfamiliar with it, it could be seen as implying that people in the 'First world' can't have problems. However, that's not really the 
sense it which it is usually used - in modern English usage, it's used to mean 'silly problems'.

- Then we go back to  *Chain Lightning*, and confirm that as well as being musically 'blues', it's legitimately 'blues' from a lyrical point of view as well:

> However, a Jewish man writing about the sick allure of a fascist rally is right up there for blues-approved subversion with Red House or Empty Bed Blues, so, as long as you get the irony, the song is about industrial-scale sufferin'.

To me, the 'however' there is simply drawing the contrast between this legitimate blues topic (Nazis) and 'silly' topics that don't seem like legitimate blues; and the point of mentioning Jewishness is simply that a Jewish person is perhaps especially well-placed to lament Nazism. I didn't read anything else into it.

Natural language is almost always subjective and ambiguous and I'm not saying my way of interpreting this post is the only way, or the right way - but I would give the poster the benefit of any doubt here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76245/discussion-on-answer-by-topo-morto-answer-on-what-is-it-about-the-blues-chord-pr).